# Can't resolve ModelService and EMenuService

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm following Vogella's lessons on eclipse plugin. For this purpose I imported all provided examples unfortunately not being able to resolve two classes:

class org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.ModelService in com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contribute.processor plugin

and org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.modeling.EMenuService in com.example.e4.rcp.todo plugin.

Both com.example.e4.rcp.todo.contribute.processor and com.example.e4.rcp.todo pluging contain all required plugins in their dependencies as required by the exercise (namely 
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.swt and org.eclipse.ui.model.workbench in the first).

It seems packages org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.modeling and org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling are contained elsewhere but I can't find where.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Some classes where moved for Eclipse 4.4 (Luna).

There is no `ModelService` class, the `EModelService` class is in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench` plugin.

The `EMenuService` is in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.services` plugin